# locking a resource via lock within try. Is it wrong?

Tags: c#, exception, synchronization

Is there anything wrong with using lock with a try block? I remember reading somewhere that we should always try to put minimum amount of code within try block and lock itself internally uses a try-finally block, do you guys see something wrong here.I need to deal with the fact that the code within that lock block can throw exception

```
try  
{  
   lock(syncblk)  
   {  
        // do some processing  
    }  

}  
catch(Exception e)  
{  
    // do something with exception  
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is correct. The `lock` statement ensures that the lock is released at the end of the block, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Jim: You say that like its a good thing. **That's a bad thing.** If an unexpected exception is thrown then releasing the lock prevents a deadlock, sure, but it also unlocks access to state that is now so broken that it caused an exception!

Comment: @Jim: What he's doing is correct if all you are considering is whether the lock is unlocked when the code completes *for whatever reason*. That might be a goal in and of itself for *someone*, but it is hardly a good way to write good software.

Comment: @Eric: Point taken. Seems I saved the tree and let the forest burn.

Comment: @Eric: There are three reasons to use locks: (1) To prevent other threads from seeing the object at a time when its invariants are not met, (2) To prevent other threads from putting the object into a state which would be inconsistent with what the locking thread expects, or (3) to avoid changing an item in a way that a thread who has acquired it for reason #2 might not expect.  If code which acquires lock for reason #2 or #3 throws an exception, there is nothing wrong with releasing the lock.  I would further suggest that if #1 is a concern, the proper remedy would be to...

Comment: @Eric: ... have an "IsInvalid" flag, and have any thread which will temporarily put an object into an invalid state acquire a lock, set IsInvalid, and do its manipulations.  Once the manipulations are complete and the object's state is again valid, clear the IsInvalid flag and release the lock.  Code which acquires the lock should ensure IsInvalid isn't set; if it is, it should fail.  If desired, the lock can be wrapped in code to ensure IsValid is clear on entry and fail if not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> I need to deal with the fact that the code within that lock block can throw exception

And there's your problem.  That's a terrible situation to be in.

Why are you locking in the first place?  Usually the reason why you lock something is because you want to implement the following logic:

- lock the door
- make a mess
- clean it up
- unlock the door

If you do that, then no one who honours the locked door ever sees the mess.

For example, you might want to swap values of variables "left" and "right" in a threadsafe manner, so you:

- take the lock
- read the left variable into tempLeft
- read the right variable into tempRight
- write tempLeft into right
- we just made a mess; the original value of 'right' has gone missing
- write tempRight into left
- we've cleaned up the mess, all is well with the world again
- release the lock

Now suppose an exception is thrown after the mess is made. What happens? **We jump straight to the unlock, leaving the mess for another thread to see**.

That's why you should **never throw an exception inside a lock**; it completely defeats the purpose of the lock! The whole point of a lock is to ensure that state is always observed to be consistent by all threads except the one responsible for cleaning up the mess.

If you have an exception that can be thrown from inside a lock, the best thing to do is to get out of that horrible situation. If you can't do that, then make sure that you can either (1) destroy the process utterly as soon as the exception escapes the lock, so that the mess you made cannot cause data loss or other harm -- do a [FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx) and nuke the process from orbit, it's the only way to be sure -- or (2) write rollback code that undoes whatever operation you were attempting *before* the lock is exited; that is, clean up the mess back to the original state.

If the latter is your strategy then don't put the try block *outside* the lock; it's useless there because **the instant control leaves the lock via the exception another thread can be crashing and dying because of the mess you left exposed to it**.  Put the try that deals with the exception *inside* the lock:

```
lock(whatever)
{
    try
    {
        MakeAMess();
    }
    finally
    {
        CleanItUp();
        // Either by completing the operation or rolling it back 
        // to the pre-mess state
    }
}
```

If you have strong reliability requirements then dealing with locked critical sections which can throw exceptions is an extremely difficult programming task best left to experts; you might consider using a **[constrained execution region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx)** if you find yourself in this situation a lot.

Comment: There are many, many reasons for acquiring a lock.  Assuming that any exception thrown within a lock will leave things in a messy state is excessively pessimistic.  Indeed, I would guess that the vast majority of locks are acquired by code which never writes to the protected data structure, but merely wants to avoid having other code do so, and that the majority of locks acquired by code which does write to a data structure are intended to prevent inconsistency between the data structure and locally-cached information or "plans" about it, rather than between parts of the data structure itself.

Comment: Consider an AppendableList, for example, which works like a list but the only operation supported is add-at-end.  When it's necessary to grow the list, a new array is created, the old items are copied to it, the list's array reference is pointed at the new array, the new item is written there, and the item count is incremented.  The AppendableList itself would be in a consistent state at all times during the add operation, but nonetheless Add would not be thread-safe.  If an "add" operaton were suspended and a second thread were allowed to add to the list, the data structure would be fine...

Comment: ...until the first thread attempted to finish its operation.  If the first thread were to partially complete its operation, but could be guaranteed never to come back and finish it, there would be no problem with making the data structure available to other threads.  While I would agree with you that code which leaves data in an invalid state should either clean it up before releasing the lock, or else have some means of signalling that the data is in an invalid state, I think that assuming any exception thrown within a lock will corrupt the state is being far too pessimistic.

Comment: @supercat: Assuming that any exception thrown within a lock will leave things in a messy state is not excessively pessimistic.  The very fact that you took a lock implies that you expect the lock to protect *something*.  If losing that protection is not going to break anything, why are you using a lock at all?

Comment: @supercat: I certainly take your point, which could be summed up as "throwing out of a read lock does not corrupt anything". Sure. But let's look at the bigger picture here.  The presumed scenario then is **reading something protected by a critical section caused an exception**. Does that sound like a good situation to be in?  Exactly what is being done in this critical section that *reading alone* causes an exception??? This sounds like a bug that needs to be fixed, not a mainline scenario.

Comment: Moreover: given that reading alone caused an exception, does this seem like a good candidate for immediately releasing the lock and letting *another* thread wake up and crash too? This sounds like a recipe for crashing every worker thread in the process. Exceptions are supposed to be *exceptional*, not expected control flow. I expect code inside locks to be the *most relible code in the system*; that stuff shouldn't ever be throwing exceptions.

Comment: @Brian: I just stated why.  The fundamental reason is that users of an object (reading or writing) will often effectively cache information from it, and will malfunction if their expectations about the object are invalidated.  Consider an AppendableList described above, with sixteen items (matching the array size), where someone tries to add another item.  The Add method starts by creating a new array and copying all the items from it.  Note that the original list has not yet been modified, so an exception that occurs here would leave the list as it was.

Comment: @Brian: Next, the AppendableList's array reference is made to point to the new list.  All of the class's invariants still hold, even though there's not yet a new item.  Next, the new item is written to a vacant spot.  Since the contents of the array beyond the specified Count are "don't care", the AppendableList is still valid.  If the thread were to abandon its efforts, it would be as though it had never done anything except expand the array.  Finally, the Count is updated.  Now the operation is complete.

Comment: And one other comment: the smart thing to do in a reliable system is to be pessimistic. An unhandled exception means that something is unexpectedly wrong, and it could be *anything*. Without evidence that things are good, in that scenario you should be pessimistic and assume that everything is wrong until proven otherwise. Hoping for the best and muddling on can make things a lot worse. Of course, it depends on the nature of the program. If the compiler gets in a bad state and crashes, no big deal. If the database controller gets in a bad state and loses data, that's a big deal.

Comment: @Brian: If there were no locking, two Add operations could conflict and try to write into the same array slot, causing corruption.  Any thread performing an Add operation, however, could safely have its lock stolen away *provided the thread yielding the lock never tries to complete the 'Add' operation*.  In case of an exception, any effort to perform the 'Add' would be abandoned, so that requirement would hold.

Comment: @supercat: The reason you took the lock is because you expected Add operations to sometimes happen at the same time.  If an exception is thrown, the thread that was trying to perform the Add will almost certainly abandon it (unless that isn't what your exception handler does), but one of the other threads trying to perform add operations that are waiting right in front of a `lock` statement (you've already admitted that such threads exist) will immediately enter the lock (since it was unlocked after the exception was thrown), oblivious to the fact that the other thread threw an exception.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I think you probably deal with a different level of code from most programmers, and so advise that might be appropriate in low-level programming may not be applicable elsewhere.  You state that "reading something protected by a critical section caused an exception".  It may be that in the code you write the normal paradigm is to acquire and release locks as quickly as possible, but in a lot of application programming locks acquired with coarser granularity.  In many cases, an exception thrown while holding a lock on Foo will have nothing to do with Foo.  There's no reason...

Comment: @Eric Lippert: ...Foo should be invalidated by an exception that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Brian: Something like an Add is simple enough that it's unlikely an exception would occur during it; I offered it as a simple example of code which would need to be done within a lock even though it never leaves an object in an invalid state.  A common pattern would be for code to acquire a lock and enumerate over a collection, doing with each item an operation that's expected to be quick and easy; an exception in the process may indicate that the data in the collection is not amenable to what one was trying to do, but that wouldn't imply a problem with the collection.

Comment: @Brian: It may indicate a problem with assumptions one had made about the collection (e.g. in searching through a collection of items bought and sold to find the one with the highest percentage profit, one might neglect to consider that an item might have been acquired free), but such a mistake in one thread shouldn't prevent other threads from using the data.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I tend to be of the opinion that good programs should compartmentalize failures.  To use a rough analogy, it would be bad policy to let known carriers of smallpox wander around freely, but it would be just as bad to nuke every city where someone might possibly have a cold.  I do think it would be good to have a lock wrapper which made it easy to keep track of whether the locked object was in a safe or dangerous state.  Perhaps in your code locked objects are almost always in 'dangerous' state, but that's not the norm in applications.

Comment: @supercat: Actually, I think Eric's position gives him unique and valuable perspective.  Maybe I'm being presumptive about Eric's experience, but I imagine he speaks not only from his experience as a language designer but also with his experience with code from users telling him (and perhaps his colleagues) about problems they have encountered with their code.  Regardless, even if ignoring a best practice will usually not cause problems, that is insufficient justification.  I'd expect more.  E.g., it's safe to ignore this practice because of XX, and it is necessary to ignore it because of YY.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: One more thing: I would suggest that if a data structure does get corrupted, attempts to access it should throw exceptions rather than deadlock.

Comment: @supercat: Well, yes, but that kinda begs the question. If the data structure is intact enough to know that it ought to be throwing "I'm corrupt" exceptions instead of deadlocking then the data structure is probably intact enough to simply fix itself up into a consistent state. The problem with corrupt data structures is that they don't *know* that they're corrupt. (Insert the "Sixth Sense" joke of your choice here.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: My solution to that would be to have a lock wrapper with an "IsDangerousState" flag.  Anything which would put the protected data into a dangerous state is responsible for setting the flag first, and for ensuring that the flag gets cleared before returning.  If the lock is released without clearing the IsDangerousState flag, any efforts to acquire it except via an AcquirePossiblyDangerousLock call would throw an exception.  Code should know when it might be putting a protected object into a dangerous state, and when the state is no longer dangerous.

Comment: @supercat: I totally take your point. But again, this is somewhat of a question-begging situation. The presumption now is that everything is possibly wrong *except the IsDangerousState flag*. First, what guarantees that *it* is correct? The assumption here is that *state is arbitrarily and unexpectedly wrong*, so why should this state be any different? I say spend the time you would have spent implementing this flag correctly on ensuring that the data doesn't get corrupted in the first place!

Comment: @Eric Lippert: My point is that the vast majority of exceptions that could occur while holding a moderate-granularity lock are neither going to corrupt any data guarded by the lock, nor imply that the data guarded by the lock has been corrupted somewhere else.  Failure to properly set the IsDangerousState flag before doing actions which could cause corruption if interrupted would be no more or less dangerous than a failure to acquire the lock before messing with the data.  Any mechanisms to prevent the latter could also prevent the former.

Comment: @supercat "My point is that the vast majority of exceptions that could occur while holding a moderate-granularity lock are neither going to corrupt any data guarded by the lock, nor imply that the data guarded by the lock has been corrupted somewhere else." I wholly refute that presumption purely based on previous experience with exceptions I have seen....

Comment: ...Almost all exceptions that hit at runtime are the result of: external resources expected to behave 'properly' not doing so (databases, file systems, ect) Since accessing these inside a lock implies real serious distributed transactions (or just laziness on the part of the programmer) the relevant transaction unrolls should be handled inside the lock...

Comment: ...The rest are coding errors (i.e. someone has a bug) at which point all your invariants (outside of contractual ones) go out the window so you should take yourself down as close as possible to the initial problem (i.e. right now). The final set is bad behaviour due to exceeding some hard limits (addressable memory/stack space is a common one) which imply the app should get the hell out of dodge asap.

Comment: The onus would be on you to prove such an extraordinary claim with hard stats (even if they only applied to your world, rather than the general case)

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: Sorry--I overgeneralized from the fact that in many cases the vast majority of times a lock is acquired, it will be by code which never puts it into an internally-inconsistent state even momentarily (consider that this is the whole reason ReaderWriterLocks exist), to the presumption that most exceptions which are thrown while locks are held would occur in such code.  Different problem domains have different patterns of what exceptions can occur; I'll grant that there are certainly problem domains where my statement would not be true.  That being said...

Comment: ...I still think that deadlocking on an attempt to access a potentially-corrupt object is far inferior to having the attempt throw an exception.  Also, as I've said before, I think a fundamental problem with exception handling is that the hierarchy provides no useful indication about what happened as a consequence of a failed operation.  Ultimately, that's what really matters.  If an application calls "GetDocumentFile" in response to the user's "File Open..." request and it doesn't work, the vast majority of things that could cause it to fail...

Comment: ...would not say anything negative about the state of the rest of the system.  If the exception hierarchy were more useful, one could catch all the myriad exceptions which would mean "The operation didn't happen; nothing else was affected by the attempt" and allow the user to continue working with other documents without any risk of those other documents being corrupted, and yet still catch exceptions indicating "The system is on fire!  Run for your lives!".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it your way but here is the MSDN description on lock for your information.  Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx for more info.

> Using the lock (C#) or SyncLock
>   (Visual Basic) keyword is generally
>   preferred over using the Monitor class
>   directly, both because lock or
>   SyncLock is more concise, and because
>   lock or SyncLock insures that the
>   underlying monitor is released, even
>   if the protected code throws an
>   exception. This is accomplished with
>   the finally keyword, which executes
>   its associated code block regardless
>   of whether an exception is thrown.

So I am not sure what kind of exception you are referring to but if you concern is that you may not be able to release the lock because of exception, you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: -1: He doesn't have to worry about *the lock being left locked*, but he should definitely worry about the state of whatever made him introduce a lock in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

you can always use the longer syntax like this:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try {
   ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
finally {
   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```

Comment: -1: And why would he want to do that? What difference does it make? Does it solve anything at all?