# Performance degradation when using lock inside try

Tags: c#

I have a `MockHttpListener` callback used in unit testing. I added a lock to it as shown below:

```
public void HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    try
    {
        lock (m_guard)
        {
            do something short;
        }

        do the actual handling (longer)
    }
    catch (HttpListenerException e)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I encountered a problem where the test failed due to "taking too long" criteria we have (I did not encounter this problem in the test prior to the addition of the lock.)

I tried many things to identify the problem and the only thing which fixed the issue was taking the lock outside the try block:

```
public void HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    lock (m_guard)
    {
        do something short;
    }
    try
    {
        do the actual handling (longer)
    }
    catch (HttpListenerException e)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The behavior change is consistent in the regard that the lock location relative to the try block affected the duration it took the test to complete.

Anyone has any idea as to the reason?

Comment: consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997360/locking-a-resource-via-lock-within-try-is-it-wrong. It gonna give you an idea why it happens.

Comment: @hazevich That doesn't tell you *why* it's slower, but it does tell you that *you should never allow an unhandled exception to escape from a `lock` block*. You need to use `try/finally` INSIDE the `lock` block to clean things up. But that doesn't help the OP here, methinks.

Comment: i read the thread in the link but it discusses the correctness of using a lock within a try block. i am only interested in the performance impact. the lock block for all consideration can be thought to be composed only of:m_some_member++; and nothing else so it is quite safe by itself.

Comment: And if you add a try - Catch inside the lock? Any difference?

Comment: i did not try to add it inside the lock since it made no sense. the content of the lock is to protect numeric members handling (read, increment, etc..). nothing more.

Comment: If you're just reading and then conditionally incrementing, you might try using a ReaderWriterLockSlim (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a lock.  An interlock (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) might also be a good option in certain circumstances.

Comment: I tried to measure this in a separate program, but can't find a noticable difference between the two approaches. I probably screwed up in my test app, but do you have any idea about the ratio of performance difference you're experiencing?

Comment: Does it take *too long* or does it *hang*? If the latter, it suggests something wrong with the locking logic itself (any change to the code could alter timing). Actually, this could be the cause of the former as well, though it's less likely. What happens in the *other* places this lock is taken?

Comment: It may be that by placing it within the try/catch block, your lock statement is still timing-out but it's exception is being caught and buried. Are you outputing that exception?
Did you configure your unit-tests to bug-out after a certain time? If so, then this is expected behavior: with the lock, it waits, then complains about timing-out. Inside the block, that complaint gets eaten.

Comment: If it takes too long - did you run some .Net profiler (e.g. dotTrace) to see where is this time spend?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a deadlock - does the "do something short" code call into any code which itself takes a lock?

The following code works as expected - not saying this is a good idea, but it terminates without issues.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Locks.DoStuff(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(e => 9999 - e).ToList());
    }
}

static class Locks
{
    public static void DoStuff(List<int> blah)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (blah)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < blah.Count; i++)
                {
                    blah[i] = 1000 / blah[i];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Exception - divided by zero");
        }
    }
}
```